# Exporting and importing Express modules

Tags: express, module, routes, require

I have 3 files.
1.  server.js --> has all the packages and running all the code from this file
2.  friends.js -->is a module that  carries an array with all the pushed data from client side
3. apiRoutes.js --> is a routing module, that has the task to perform  the route /api/friends to display a json object from friends.js

When I import friends.js module and apiRoutes.js module into the server.js, it is not recognizing friends array from friends.js 
**

> How do we get access to data from friends.js when routed as
>   /api/friends when we run server.js

Server.js:

```
// server.js
//Incorporate dependencies
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

// console.log(htmlRoutes);
//call express
var app = express();
//requiring htmlRoute.js
require('../app/routing/htmlRoutes.js')(app, path);
//requiring apiRoutes.js
require('../app/routing/apiRoutes.js')(app);

// Declare a port
var PORT = 3000;

//data parsing
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//requiring the friends.js
require('../app/data/friends.js')


//Listen to port
app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log('listening to PORT: '+ PORT);
});
```

friends.js

```
// friends.js
// array of objects
module.exports = function(app){
var friends =[
    {   
        routeName: "ahmed",
        name:"Ahmed",
        photourl:"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_400_400/p/6/005/064/1bd/3435aa3.jpg",
        questions:[
                    5,
                    1,
                    4,
                    4,
                    5,
                    1,
                    2,
                    5,
                    4,
                    1
        ]
    }   
]

//retreiving stored objects with person's data
app.post("/survey", function(req, res){
    var incomingPerson = req.body;
    incomingPerson.routeName = incomingPerson.name.replace(/\s+/g, "").toLowerCase();
    console.log(incomingPerson);
    // friends.push(person);
})


}
```

apiRoutes.js

```
// apiRoutes.js
//PARAMETERIZATION
module.exports = function(app){
//A GET route with the url `/api/friends`. This will be used to display a JSON of all possible friends.
app.get("/api/friends/:whoDoIWantToSee?", function(req, res){
    var chosen = req.params.whoDoIWantToSee;
    res.json(friends);
    // if(chosen){
    //     res.json(friends.chosen);
    // }

    // console.log(chosen);
});
//A POST routes `/api/friends`. This will be used to handle incoming survey results. This route will also be used to handle the compatibility logic. 
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant portions of your code in your question.  The generic answer is that you use module imports and exports appropriately in order to share data between modules.  The specific answer depends upon your specific code.  We aren't going to teach general modules and how to use them here (that's too long a topic), but we can help you with your specific issue if you include your code.

Comment: Thank you for responding back.  I added the pictures of my code.  Hope that helps to see it more specifically.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Code needs to pasted into your question and formatted properly as code to make it readable.  We don't take code in pictures for a whole variety of reasons.  And, code should not only be via an external link either because external links have a habit of changing or breaking or disappearing over time, rendering the question meaningless as a long term reference (which is one of stack overflow's goals).  Please paste your code into the question as text.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong formatted code.  Hope I formatted it properly for looking at the code this time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export the `friends` array from your friends.js module like this:

```
// array of objects
const friends = [
    {   
        routeName: "ahmed",
        name:"Ahmed",
        photourl:"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_400_400/p/6/005/064/1bd/3435aa3.jpg",
        questions:[
                    5,
                    1,
                    4,
                    4,
                    5,
                    1,
                    2,
                    5,
                    4,
                    1
        ]
    }   
];

module.exports = function(app){

    //retreiving stored objects with person's data
    app.post("/survey", function(req, res){
        var incomingPerson = req.body;
        incomingPerson.routeName = incomingPerson.name.replace(/\s+/g, "").toLowerCase();
        console.log(incomingPerson);
        // friends.push(person);
    });
    return friends;

};

module.exports.friends = friends;
```

Then, anywhere you want access to the singleton `friends` array, you can do this:

```
const friends = require('./friends.js').friends;
```

Comment: so when I do that when I type in the url /api/friends, it gives me an error saying friends is not defined

Comment: @VeenaUppalapati - Did you put `const friends = require('./friends.js').friends;` in the module you're trying to use it in?  You have to put that in every module where you want to reference the `friends` array.

Comment: oh wow!!! yess it works!! Thank you!  I haven't been requiring it in apiRoutes.  Now it works!